# A sufficient condition for a block diagonal matrix to be positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite, block-matrices, schur-complement

Let

$$P = \begin{bmatrix} A & B \\ B^\top & D\end{bmatrix}$$

where blocks $A$ and $D$ are positive definite. All the matrices $A$, $B$ and $D$ are $n \times n$.

I was wondering if one could actually derive a sufficient condition in terms of the minimum or maximum eigenvalues of the matrix $A$ such that $P >0$ can be ensured?

Answer (score 1):

With the [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement), we see that $P > 0$ holds iff $D > 0$ and $A > BD^{-1}B^T$.

That said, we can guarantee that $P>0$ if $D > 0$ and $\lambda_{\min}(A) > \lambda_{\max}(BD^{-1}B^T)$.  We could simplify this somewhat by noting that we have 
$$
\lambda_{\max}(BD^{-1}B^T) \geq \lambda_{\max}(B^TB)\lambda_{\max}(D^{-1}) = \frac{\lambda_{\max}(B^TB)}{\lambda_{\min}(D)}.
$$

Comment: [+1] $C$ is in fact denoted by $D$ by the OP.

Comment: @JeanMarie Whoops! Good catch

Comment: Do the matrices need to be symmetric?

Comment: @FormulaWriter I think so; certainly in order for the eigenvalue-based bounds to be valid. However, if $P$ is not symmetric, then it suffices to consider the fact that $P$ is positive definite if and only if the symmetric matrix $P + P^T$ is positive definite and apply the condition.